# taskbar background app with mono

Tags: c#, background, mono, gtk

I would like to create an app built in C#/Gtk using Mono and have it act similar to Skype, in that an icon appears on the taskbar, the app runs in the background, but the user can open the UI to fiddle around with the background process.

Is this possible, and how?  Can this be written in such a way that it will work on Ubuntu and also Windows?

Comment: Each OS exposes its own API for you to consume, so you cannot find a way that works cross platform in this case.

Comment: isnt that the whole reason Gtk exists?

Comment: Gtk is only a limited widget framework, which renders the forms well. However, to integrate into Windows, you still need to hook to Windows itself, with some Windows only APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to revive this old answer, but it's ranked high in the Google search results for "notification icon mono", so I guess I'll leave a answer here. Based on the [Mono docs](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/widgets/notification-icon/):

```
Pixbuf iconImage = new Pixbuf("myIcon.png"); // The icon image to use
StatusIcon icon = new StatusIcon(iconImage);

icon.Activate += delegate {DoStuff();} // on left mouse button click
icon.PopupMenu += += delegate {DoStuff();} // on right mouse button click
icon.Visible = true;
```